# Правильная запись в csv при разборе с xml

Tags: php, массивы, xml, парсер, импорт

Нужна помощь, делаю простой разбор xml в прайс в CSV для синхронизации магазина, точнее учусь и хочу сделать. 
Задача скрипта взять xml, скачать и сделать с него CSV в заданном формате. Прошу не обращать внимание на правильность этого всего дела (в плане написания).
Собственно проблема с выводом строки с размерами (опциями), их нужно преобразовать в определенный формат для загрузки, что я и сделал.
Но при записи через fputcsv() в файл, им добавляется разделитель (запятая или точка с запятой, что поставлю), но здесь разделитель не нужен, они должны быть строкой с переносом а не массивом. Соответственно потом csv понимает это как отдельные колонки
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

По факту нужно чтобы они записывались без разделителей в одну колонку.
Код моей обработки:

```
<?php 

$filepo= file_get_contents('http://free-run.kiev.ua/yml/12345');
file_put_contents('down.xml', $filepo);

$filexml= 'down.xml';

if (file_exists($filexml))  {

   $xml = simplexml_load_file($filexml);

   $i = 1;           // Position counter
   $values = [];     // PHP array

   // Writing column headers
   $columns = array('url', '_CUSTOM_BASE_PRICE_', '_CUSTOM_BASE_CURRENCY_CODE_', 'categoryId', 'picture', 'delivery', 'name', 'description', '_OPTION_','_OPTION2_');

   $fs = fopen('synchro.csv', 'w');
   fputcsv($fs, $columns, ';');      
   fclose($fs);

   // Iterate through each <item> node
   $node = $xml->xpath('//offer');

   foreach ($node as $n) {           

       // Iterate through each child of <item> node
       $child = $xml->xpath('//offer['.$i.']/*');   

       foreach ($child as $value) {
          $values[] = $value;

       }

       $pere = "\n";
       $razmery = $n->param;
       $pieces = explode(',', $razmery);
       foreach ($pieces as $value2) {
          $values[] =  'radio|Размер|' .$value2. '|1|100|0|+|0.0000|+|0|+|0.00' .$pere; 
       }



       // Write to CSV files (appending to column headers)
       $fs = fopen('synchro.csv', 'a');
       fputcsv($fs, $values, ';');         
       fclose($fs);  

       $values = [];    // Clean out array for next <item> (i.e., row)
       $values2 = [];    // Clean out array for next <item> (i.e., row)

       $i++;            // Move to next <item> (i.e., node position)
   }
}
```

Comment: если разделитель не нужен, то и не используйте `fputcsv`, а чем проблема то?

Comment: Посмотрел внимательно, а там эти данные в массиве, преобразовал в троку и встало практически работать как нужно. Но за ответ всеравно спасибо!